# BluetoothAdapter Disable function not working

Tags: android

Bluetooth Adapter should be disabled when ever it get's on. this is the code i wrote. To disable wifi i have successfully achieved using,

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
```

manifest is defined as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```